# Code for generating oauth_Signature when you have consumer key, secret, token and tokenkey

Tags: oauth, jmeter, hmacsha1

I have to test a GET request in jmeter where I have to pass oauth signature as a parameter. I have consumer key, consumer secret, token and token secret. I want to generate it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have 2 request-

1.Post request. where you are sending consumer key, consumer secret, token and token secret as parameter.

2. Get request. where you have to pass oauth signature as a parameter.

If this is the case, use Regular expression extractor to fetch value from response 1 and pass it to request 2.

If possible share request with parameter to get better idea.